# jquery hover on table row with .live help

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table and I create rows on the fly with:

```
$('#AjaxResultTable > tbody:last').append('<tr class="row"><td class="expandResult" title="Click to expand/collapse">&#43;</td>' + id + name + suburb + state + zip + '</tr>').hide().fadeIn(200);
```

I want to change background color on rows when I hover over them and change back when I'm not.

I tried with

```
$('#AjaxResultTable tr').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
}, function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
});
```

but that didn't work so I tried with

```
$('#AjaxResultTable tr').live('hover', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#f5f5f5');
}, function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
});
```

which changes the background-color when I hover over a row but it doesn't change back to white when I'm not.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a simple event handler that toggles a class.

JS

```
$('#AjaxResultTable').delegate('tr', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

CSS

```
.hover {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

**EDIT:** Also in your example, the property should be called `backgroundColor` (instead of `background-color`)

**EDIT 2:** .live() has a few caveats, one of which is binding with .hover().  See the API doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
As of jQuery 1.4.1 the hover event can be specified (mapping to mouseenter and mouseleave, which, in turn, are mapped to mouseover and mouseout).
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing it with strictly css.   if you've got a lot going on on your page, especially with live handlers, you'll start seeing some performance degradation.

a css selector like this:  will change the background colour of all the td in the row that is hovered.

```
#YourTableId tbody tr:hover td
{
    background-color:#F0F6Fc; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes i would also do it in Css to change presentation styles..
some thing live what has been put aboce

```
#yourTableID tbody td:hover tr
{
   backgroundColor:#F0F6Fc;
    color: #FFF;
}

or .yourTableClass tr:hover
{
   backgroundColor:#F0F6Fc;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

also i think it was here but if you re using IE...7-whatever i would recommend using 
[whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html) file

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.mouseleave()` listener.. take a look here : http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the background colour to the td/th not the tr. A class based system is preferable in this situation

```
$('#AjaxResultTable tr').hover(function () {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function () {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});

tr.hover td, tr.hover th { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
```